# Complex loop with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm struggling to return results using this:

```
url = "http://www.mollymaid.co.uk/counties/aberdeenshire.aspx"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.css(".location").each do |location|
  puts location.at_css(".city_odd, city_even").text
end
```

This was just trying to get results from the URL above. I can change it to just return one result with:

```
url = "http://www.mollymaid.co.uk/counties/aberdeenshire.aspx"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.at_css(".city_odd").text
```

but I don't understand how to iterate through all the results especially as theres a `.city_even` CSS tag that I need to add in there. If I insert this as well it just gets ignored.

Furthermore I want to remove the "- Serviced by MOLLY MAID Aberdeen" text from the results. Each line of data appears as "Altens Ind Estate - Serviced by MOLLY MAID Aberdeen". Would `chomp` be correct here?

In an ideal world I would like to automatically go through all of this list doing the same though I am unsure if this is possible? http://www.mollymaid.co.uk/servicelist.aspx

Comment: You need to add a small, reduced sample, of the HTML in question, instead of asking us to retrieve it and look through it. Remember, you're asking people to take their free time to help you, so it behooves you to make it as easy as possible for them to do so. In other words, help us help you.

Comment: You missed a `.` in `.city_even`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use `xpath` instead as it's a little more expressive. Here's a working example:

```
url = "http://www.mollymaid.co.uk/counties/aberdeenshire.aspx"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.xpath("//div[@class='city_even' or @class='city_odd']/a/text()").each do |location|
    puts location
end
```

If you read the xpath expression out loud, it means: find all divs in the document who have a class attribute equal to 'city_even' or 'city_odd', then find all anchor tags who are children of those divs, then find all text nodes who are children of those anchor tags.

When Nokogiri returns with a NodeSet containing the city names, this code iterates through each city name and `puts` it.

Comment: Thats brilliant thanks! Just gotta work out what all that means now!

Comment: When I was learning xpath, I found this tutorial really helpful: http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html

Comment: But if you read it out loud from left to right, that specific xpath means something like "find all divs in the document who have a class attribute equal to 'city_even' or 'city_odd', then find all anchor tags who are children of those divs, then find all text nodes who are children of those anchor tags".

Comment: I've gotten a couple of downvotes on this answer, but none of the downvoters have stopped to explain their reason for downvoting. Why the downvotes folks?

Comment: yes totally worked and really helped me out. I'm not really sure this place really works, there seems to be a lot of people not actually helping people out - isn;t that what its for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `.location` container for `.city_even` and `.city_odd`. Try instead using the `#city_list` ID (which should be a class, not an ID) maybe that will work:

```
doc.css("#city_list").each do |city|
  city1 = city.css(".city_odd").text
  city1 = city1[0, city1.index(" - Serviced by")]
  city2 = city.css(".city_even").text
  city2 = city2[0, city2.index(" - Serviced by")]

  puts city1
  puts city2
end
```

or better yet, only get the `a` inside the `city_even`/`city_odd`:

```
doc.css("#city_list").each do |city|
  city1 = city.css(".city_odd a").text
  city2 = city.css(".city_even a").text

  puts city1
  puts city2
end
```

Comment: Almost worked but got this error:Danestone
 - Serviced by MOLLY MAID Aberdeen
testscrape.rb:8:in `block in <main>': undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:237:in `block in each'
 from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:236:in `upto'
 from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.3.1/lib/nokogiri/xml/node_set.rb:236:in `each'
 from testscrape.rb:7:in `<main>'
localhost:workspace user$

Comment: I believe `#at_css` searches for the first occurrence and returns a node. Try just `#css`.

Comment: Try seeing what `city` is and seeing if you can call `css` on it like @thohl suggested. If that doesn't work, `puts city.content` should output the HTML

Comment: Hey thohl that worked a treat - any ideas how I'd nip the "- Serviced by MOLLY MAID Aberdeen" off the results?

Comment: `str = city.css(".city_odd").text` and `str[0, str.index(" - Serviced by")]` should do the trick

Comment: sorry how do I add the str = city.css(".city_odd").text and str[0, str.index(" - Serviced by")] together?

Comment: you probably wouldn't want to do that since it would call `city.css()` twice, but it would be like: `city.css(".city_odd").text[0, city.css(".city_odd").text.index(" - Serviced by")]`

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
url = "http://www.mollymaid.co.uk/counties/aberdeenshire.aspx"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc.css(".city_odd a, .city_even a").map &:text
```

Is this what you want, i.e., print the text of all the links? Because the `div#city_list` elements (if the HTML was correct, there should be only one) on that page only contain links and the text you want to remove.

By the way, I recommend using the command line version of Nokogiri for testing your CSS. You should get a much faster feedback cycle with the following:

```
wget http://www.mollymaid.co.uk/counties/aberdeenshire.aspx 
cat aberdeenshire.aspx  | nokogiri -e 'puts $_.css(".city_odd a, .city_even a").map &:text'
```

Comment: "cat aberdeenshire.aspx  | nokogiri -e 'puts $_.css(".city_odd a, .city_even a").map &:text'" Ugh. Instead use: `nokogiri -e 'puts $_.css(".city_odd a, .city_even a").map &:text' < aberdeenshire.aspx`. It's faster and simpler and less typing.

Comment: Thanks, @theTinMan. I usually prefer the `cat` version  because it goes from left to right.

Comment: Using `cat` to pipe into an app that reads STDIN, has been discussed many times all over the internets. While it's logical to read, it's also inefficient. Stick that operation in the middle of a loop and do it a couple million times and you'll be talking about real time differences. It's a hard habit to break, but being aware of the issues helps.

Comment: In this case, though, the efficiency difference is absolutely negligible (there's a much much larger bottleneck in the nokogiri/ruby part) so it comes down to taste. Also, I usually end up modifying the filter part more often than the input in CLI experiments such as this one and having to navigate around `< somefile` is an annoyance. I could put it at the beginning (`<somefile mycommand`), but I that might be confusing to people.